# ArgumentError passing RSpec get method a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to pass an ID to the get method in an RSpec test of a non resourceful route, and I get an argument error.

Here's the test:

```
describe MoviesController do
  describe "search directors" do
    it 'calls the model method that find similar movies' do
      movie1 = Movie.create(:title => "Star Wars1", :director => "George", :rating => "R")
      movie2 = Movie.create(:title => "Star Wars2", :director => "George", :rating => "R")
      get :search_directors, {:id => 1}
    end
  end
end
```

search_directions action in MoviesController:

```
  def search_directors
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movies = Movie.similar_movies(@movie)
  end
```

Here's my routes:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  root :to => redirect('/movies')
  get '/movies/search_directors/:id', to:'movies#search_directors'
end
```

Movies model (movie.rb)

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_ratings
    %w(G PG PG-13 NC-17 R)
  end
  def self.similar_movies
    Movie.where(director: self.director)
  end
end
```

And the error:

```
  Failure/Error: get 'search_directors', {:id => 1}
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
 # ./app/models/movie.rb:5:in `similar_movies'
 # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:66:in `search_directors'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
```

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't in your `search_directors` method?  Could you include the full trace that came with the error?

Comment: You're right, it is search_directors where the error originates, I've updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: Great,  so can you post your movie.rb? Line 5 is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I think see the problem now, I've added what you requested and the controller action as well (which I mistakenly thought was empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is here...

```
  def self.similar_movies
    Movie.where(director: self.director)
  end
```

There's no class method `director` and you're not passing an instance in.  One way to fix this...

```
  def self.similar_movies(movie)
    Movie.where(director: movie.director)
  end
```

But a better way would be make it an instance method....

```
  def similar_movies 
    Movie.where(director: self.director)
  end
```

And then you can replace...

```
@movies = Movie.similar_movies(@movie)
```

with the much nicer...

```
@movies = @movie.similar_movies
```

You don't even need the `search_directors` method in the controller, just reference (in your views) `@movie.similar_movies`

A further suggested improvement... in `similar_movies` you likely don't want to include `self` in the returned collection (the main movie should not show up in the list of similar movies), so:

```
  def similar_movies 
    Movie.where(director: director).where.not(id: id)
  end
```

Note (by the way) the use of `director` is fine, you don't need `self.director`.  You only need `self` when doing assignments.

```
# creates a local variable
director = "Alfred" 
# updates the model attribute
self.director = "Alfred"
```

Comment: Excellent, this is a very clear explanation and has helped my understanding significantly, I've upvoted but my reputation is too low for it to show up yet! Thanks again Steve.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can accept the answer which will be just as good as voting up :) The option to accept the answer should be there to the left of the answer.